# How can I know for which branch a changeset was made at github?

Tags: git, github, playframework

Hi 
I'm follow the changes of the playframework with an rss-feed on lighthouse
http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/events.atom. It works pretty cool an I like it, but there is one thing I'm missing: How can I see for which branch the change is made? For example https://github.com/playframework/play/commit/69f747cb47749a90b7e54098af2a35304a315a20. Was this made in the master branch or in 1.1.x?

I thought that this is a common problem, but I didn't find a solution.

Niels

Comment: There is probably a more direct answer to your question, but you could use [this feed which comes directly from github](https://github.com/playframework/play/commits/master.atom) and is for the master branch only. There is a similar feed for the 1.1.x branch too.

Comment: Well to follow changes is easy. You can use lighthouse for it. So you have perhaps from a mailing group a direct link to a changeset, how can you know in which branch this works?

Comment: I have the same question.  I don't want to have to search through each branch's feed to find the changeset.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the branch that you want to see its commit history. Use Switch Branches menu thats just below the project name, than it will only show the commit history of that branch in Commits page.

Also, you can check the Network tab to see a visual history. Located at https://github.com/playframework/play/network

Comment: Well it's the same as the comment above. Was I want is the following:
I get a link to a changeset, with the hint that there is the solution of my problem, perhaps from a bugreport. Now I want to know in which branch the changes was made.